# Catch javascript event on fields created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, dom

I have an input field with class named "form_inputext1".

I am doing some action when pressing ENTER, using this code:

```
jQuery(".form_inputext1").keypress(function(event) {
      console.log(event.keyCode);
      if (event.keyCode == '13' || event.which == '13') {
         event.preventDefault();

         jQuery("#addMoreOptions").click();

         return false;
      }
    });
```

This part works fine. One of the things it does is it adds one more input field of class "form_inputext1" as a result of an ajax call.

The problem is this newly added field is not associated with the keypress event I wrote. I assume that's because the jQuery code only attach the event to the existing fields, not to the fields added in the future.

How can I work around this? I want this function to apply to onkeypress even for inputs that are not in the DOM yet.

Comment: You can use [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery - (re)wiring dynamically generated elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581518/jquery-rewiring-dynamically-generated-elements)

Comment: so many good answers, will be hard to choose the "accepted"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YOu can use Jquery's [**live**](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
jQuery(".form_inputext1").live('keypress', function(event) {
      console.log(event.keyCode);
      if (event.keyCode == '13' || event.which == '13') {
         event.preventDefault();

         jQuery("#addMoreOptions").click();

         return false;
      }
});
```

Or you can add the keypress event when you create the element, which will give you much better performance:

```
$('.clicker').click(function() {
    $('<div class="clicker" />').text('new').appendTo($(this)).keypress(function(event) {
        alert(event.which);
    })
})
```

[**Example of that**](http://jsfiddle.net/rwkr5/)

Comment: In your second solution, will my function have access to the "event" object?

Comment: If however I declare the function somewhere and just pass it by name onkeypress="callMyFunction();", do I still have access to event?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$('.form_inputext1').live('keypress', function ( event ) {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.live()` or `.delegate()` instead.

http://api.jquery.com/live/

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Answer (score 0):

If you use the jQuery live method to bind an event to a class, it will apply even to elements that are added to the DOM after you call the live method.

Documentation:  http://api.jquery.com/live/

From the documentation:

---

To bind a click handler to the target element using this method:

```
$('.clickme').live('click', function() {
  // Live handler called.
});
```

And then later add a new element:

```
$('body').append('Another target');
```

Then clicks on the new element will also trigger the handler.